# Как побороть 431-ю ошибку в nuxt-приложении?

Tags: node.js, nginx, typescript, nuxt.js

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: разрабатываем с командой интернет-магазин, запустили приложение в прод; маркетологи запускают всякие рекламные кампании и льют трафик на приложение. Все эти рекламные сервисы подсовывают дикие utm-метки в query-параметры и сетят хреналион кук. Наше приложение, разумеется, стоит за **nginx**, и на **nginx** подняли лимиты для заголовков до конских размеров, это есть. Но сам нодовский сервак имеет по умолчанию ограничения на заголовки в **8КБ** (*16КБ, зависит от версии ноды*). И приложение отваливает с **431-й ошибкой**. Сначала я грешил на nging. А потом на локалке воспроизвел ошибку нагенерив несколько сотен кук. Думал еще может **PM2** хрень какую-то делает, но нет, это нода, сомнений нет. И теперь вопрос встал ребром: писать ли свой сервер нодовский под **nuxt** с билдером и гибко настраивать через него все или же есть какой-то вариант этого избежать и средствами **nuxt** пофиксить проблему? Всегда же лучше меньше кода, чем больше, так как это все нам еще поддерживать придется.)

И еще: ситуация слегка осложняется тем, что мы используем связку **nuxt + typescript**. То есть какие-то классические решения на **express** не заходят.

Знаю, что в ноде есть консольный параметр `--max-http-header-size`, но просто так им, как понимаю, с **nuxt** не воспользоваться. Нужно именно запускать что-то вроде этого:

```
node --max-http-header-size=1500 server
```

Вообщем, какой-то ступор пока что. Буду признателен любым подсказкам и помощи в данном вопросе!

Answer (score 0):

короче, решение просто, как пробка, но до него еще нужно дойти)

```
NODE_OPTIONS='--max-http-header-size=<нужный максимум в байтах>'
```

любой параметр для ноды можно прокинуть через **NODE_OPTIONS**, подробнее тут (там полный список доступных консольных параметров) - https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_options_options